# jOOQ Query OrderBy as String

Tags: jooq

I'm getting the order by clause as a String from the application configuration.

Example

```
String orderByString = "NAME DESC, NUMBER ASC";
```

Now I want to use this order by in jOOQ query:

```
Result<KampagneRecord> records = repository.dsl()
        .selectFrom(KAMPAGNE)
        .orderBy(orderByString)
        .fetch();
```

Unfortunately orderBy does not accept a String.

Is there a way to add the order by clause to the query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the fact that jOOQ does not validate your [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/), and just wrap your string in a [`DSL.field(String)`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#field-java.lang.String-):

```java
Result<KampagneRecord> records = repository.dsl()
        .selectFrom(KAMPAGNE)
        .orderBy(field(orderByString))
        .fetch();
```

Of course, you will have to make sure that syntactical correctness is guaranteed, and SQL injection is prevented.

Some edge cases that rely on jOOQ being able to transform your SQL's `ORDER BY` clause might stop working, but in your simple query example, this would not apply.

An alternative solution, in very simple cases, is to preprocess your string. It seems as though this would work:

```java
String orderByString = "NAME DESC, NUMBER ASC";

List<SortField<?>> list =
Stream.of(orderByString.split(","))
    .map(String::trim)
    .map(s -> s.split(" +"))
    .map(s -> {
        Field<?> field = field(s[0]);
        return s.length == 1
                ? field.sortDefault()
                : field.sort("DESC".equalsIgnoreCase(s[1])
                      ? SortOrder.DESC
                      : SortOrder.ASC
                  );
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);
```

This list can now be passed to the `orderBy()` clause.

Comment: Great this works! Thank you. I implemented the alternative solution but it turned out that I have to support order by clauses like "CASE WHEN NVL(GUELTIGBIS,SYSDATE) < SYSDATE THEN 2 ELSE 1 END ASC, POSNR ASC, ARTNR ASC, ARTNRKAMP ASC"

Comment: I see, then that doesn't work. The parser might eventually support parsing standalone sort specifications, but right now, it doesn't.